# getting the length of the array of objects inside an object

Tags: javascript

I would like to map the object and get the number/length of replies that can be found in `replies` in this case 2. I have fetched this data from the API and is unable to get the number of replies that can be found here.

```
let data = [ 
   { 
      "feedbackId":32,
      "sender":"12345"
      "comment":"Test Comment",
      "replies":[ 
         { 
            "feedbackLogId":32,
            "feedbackReplyLogId":1,
            "comments":"So this is 1",
            "createdBy":"Jack",
         },
         { 
            "feedbackLogId":32,
            "feedbackReplyLogId":2,
            "comments":"2nd one",
            "createdBy":"Min",
         }
      ],
   }
]
```

This is what I've done. I am only able to get `1` as the length.

```
let repliesToRender = data.map((item) => {item.replies})
let numReplies = repliesToRender.length
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate reply per feedback using `Array.prototype.map`

for calculting total number of replies you can use `Array.prototype.reduce`

```js
let data = [{"feedbackId":32,"sender":"12345","comment":"Test Comment","replies":[{"feedbackLogId":32,"feedbackReplyLogId":1,"comments":"So this is 1","createdBy":"Jack"},{"feedbackLogId":32,"feedbackReplyLogId":2,"comments":"2nd one","createdBy":"Min"}]},{"feedbackId":32,"sender":"12345","comment":"Test Comment","replies":[{"feedbackLogId":32,"feedbackReplyLogId":1,"comments":"So this is 1","createdBy":"Jack"},{"feedbackLogId":32,"feedbackReplyLogId":2,"comments":"2nd one","createdBy":"Min"}]}]

let repliesCount = data.map(({replies}) => replies.length);
console.log('per replies',repliesCount);

let totalCount = data.reduce((a,c) => a + c.replies.length, 0);
console.log('total replies ',totalCount)
```

Comment: This solutions will take 0.47900390625ms as it's using `map` and `reduce` to traverse array. Complexity will increase with more data.

Comment: @TusharVaghela it's  `map` **OR** `reduce` depending upon the requirement, also what do you suggest otherwise? or its just an information? also how the complexity will increase with more data?

Comment: I suggest using `let {replies} = data[0];console.log(replies.length);`
This solution will take around 0.209716796875ms. With more number of replies, `map` or `reduce` will take more time.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issue in your code,

```
let repliesToRender = data.map((item) => {item.replies})
```

should be

```
let repliesToRender = data.map((item) => item.replies)
```

And map return you array so your repliesToRender will be an array of array so you need

```
let numReplies = repliesToRender[0].length
```

Or just

```
let numReplies = data.replies.length
```

---

```js
let data = [ 
   { 
      "feedbackId":32,
      "sender":"12345",
      "comment":"Test Comment",
      "replies":[ 
         { 
            "feedbackLogId":32,
            "feedbackReplyLogId":1,
            "comments":"So this is 1",
            "createdBy":"Jack",
         },
         { 
            "feedbackLogId":32,
            "feedbackReplyLogId":2,
            "comments":"2nd one",
            "createdBy":"Min",
         }
      ],
   }
]


let repliesToRender = data.map((item) => item.replies)
let numReplies = repliesToRender[0].length
console.log(numReplies)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach.
This will run faster in case of large data-sets, as it's not using loops.

```
let data = [ 
   { 
      "feedbackId":32,
      "sender":"12345",
      "comment":"Test Comment",
      "replies":[ 
         { 
            "feedbackLogId":32,
            "feedbackReplyLogId":1,
            "comments":"So this is 1",
            "createdBy":"Jack",
         },
         { 
            "feedbackLogId":32,
            "feedbackReplyLogId":2,
            "comments":"2nd one",
            "createdBy":"Min",
         }
      ],
   }
]

let {replies} = data[0];
console.log(replies.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

If replies count is needed for each of the objects, then below will return array of replies count for respective objects in order,

```
let eachObjectsRepliesCount = data.map(({replies}) => replies.length);
```

If replies count is needed for all the objects combined, then below will return the total replies count,

```
let repliesToRender = data.map((item) => item.replies)
let totalRepliesCount = repliesToRender[0].length
```